# Backwards error

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Here is the Theorem from the notes of my professor: Let $\hat{x}$ be the computer calculated solution to $Ax = b$, where $A$ is a Matrix (it's not really specified what kind of Matrix $A$ is). It follows that
$$\min \lbrace || \Delta A ||_2 ; (A + \Delta A)\hat{x} = b \rbrace = \frac{||\Delta A \hat{x}||_2}{||\hat{x}||_2} $$

What I don't understand is, the minimum up there. It implies that there are multiple $\Delta A$ which fulfil the requirement $(A + \Delta A)\hat{x} = b$. How come there can be multiple $\Delta A$? I thought the $\Delta A$ was unique.

Comment: Why would $\delta A$ be unique? Given $\hat{x}, b$ you can find infinitely many matrices $B$ such that $B \hat x = b$. In this setting you have that $\delta A = B -A$.

Answer (score 1):

I shall now demonstrate how you can find infinitely many $\Delta A$ that also satisfy $$(A + \Delta A)\hat{x} = b.$$ The key is to recognize that we more variables than we have constraints. What we have to do is to construct singular matrices $K$ such that $$K\hat{x} = 0.$$ Then $$(A + (\Delta A + K)) \hat{x} = b.$$ Constructing such a $K$ can be done as follows. Since $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is nonzero, we can extend $\hat{x}$ to a basis $$\{v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_m\}$$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\hat{x} = v_1$. We can now define a linear transformation $K : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ in any way we like, provided we take $$Kv_1 = 0.$$ The only thing that remains is obtain the representation of $K$ with respect to standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 0):

With the Lagrangian
$$
L=\frac12\|H\|_2^2+\lambda^T((A+H)\hat x-b)
$$
one gets the saddle point equation
$$
0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial H} = H^T + \hat x\lambda^T
$$
Now insert $H=-\lambda \hat x^T$ into the constraint to get
$$
A\hat x-b=\|\hat x\|_2^2\lambda
$$